# Spring-WS unable to set FaultCode.RECEIVER

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-ws

I cannot set FaultCode.RECEIVER for my fault message;
The code in response is always SERVER

Here is my response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header />
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Something wrong!</faultstring>
         <faultactor>http://fault.actor.com/actor/</faultactor>
         <detail>
            <ServiceException>
               <code>ABCD</code>
               <message>Invalid input</message>
            </ServiceException>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The fault code is SOAP-ENV:Server instead of SOAP-ENV:Receiver

Heres my exception class

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.RECEIVER, faultStringOrReason = "Something wrong!")
public class CustomFault extends RuntimeException
```

When i'm putting faultCode = FaultCode.CLIENT, it changes in response to Client, but with RECEIVER doesn't work.
For adding fault details in response i'm using SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are using soap fault 1.2 ? Since the fault code receiver did not exist in 1.1, you code might set the fault code to default which is server.

Comment: Hmm.. as i can see it's in spring-ws-core 2.2.3

Comment: by default it is soap 1.1. You need to set it to 1.2 http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#soap_11_or_12

Comment: Your'e right, thanks:)